# Linear Algebra - Spaces of Vector, Real space, and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading the linear algebra book 5th by Gilbert Strang. And there are few parts. I am confused.

Here is the definition:

The space R^n consists of all column vectors v with n components.

[4 5]^T is in R^2, (1,1,0,1,1) is in R^5

A is an m by n matrix. Its columns have m components (not n).

The column space of A is a subspace of R^M **(not R^n)**

why author try to emphasis on "not R^n"? And why it's not R^n?

Comment: What are M and n here? And what is A?

Comment: If $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix, its $n$ columns can be considered as elements of $\mathbb R^m$, so, the column space of $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^m$, it makes no sense saying that the column space of $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I guessed that I confused, because (1,1,0,1,1) is a 1 by 5 matrix. So, it's column space should from R^1? But the book also mentioned (1,1,0,1,1) is in R^5.

Comment: @Szu-HuaHuang The book is probably considering $(1,1,0,1,1)$ not as $1\times 5$ matrix, but as an element of $\mathbb{R}^5$ as a vector space, i.e. as a vector.